# Not Able to Understand how the following code is working

Tags: c++, string

https://leetcode.com/contest/biweekly-contest-51/problems/replace-all-digits-with-characters/
I tried to solve this question but i was not able to do so so i looked into the discussions and i was able to find the answer but i was still not able to understand how the third line of the code is giving me the ouput.I know this a very basic doubt but i was not able to get it. please help

```
string replaceDigits(string s) {
for (auto i = 1; i < s.size(); i += 2)
    s[i] += s[i - 1] - '0';
return s;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a leetcode account. What is this code supposed to be doing?

Comment: What *do* you understand about the line in question?

Comment: This is not `C` code.

Comment: function shift(c, x), where c is a character and x is a digit, that returns the xth character after c   Input: s = "a1b2c3d4e"
Output: "abbdcfdhe"
Explanation: The digits are replaced as follows:
- s[1] -> shift('a',1) = 'b'
- s[3] -> shift('b',2) = 'd'
- s[5] -> shift('c',3) = 'f'
- s[7] -> shift('d',4) = 'h'

Comment: @devXm -- The line of code is basic C++.  This is why sites such as LeetCode are almost worthless if you want to learn how to write C++.  Those questions on that site are meant for persons who already know the computer language they will be using to answer the question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Maybe he already knows C++ and is trying to improve his algorithm skills.

Comment: @0x499602D2 -- For a simple line of code like that, I doubt it.  Even then, using a debugger and stepping through that line of code should have been done to figure out what that line of code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is essentially asking you to replace every digit in the string with `shift(s[i-1], s[i])`.

So for every odd index `i`, you convert `s[i]` from a character to an integer (by subtracting `'0'`) and adding that to the previous character `s[i-1]`. Another way to write the third line is like this:

```
s[i] = s[i-1] + (s[i] - '0');
```

If `s[i]` is `'1'`, then `s[i] - '0'` is `1`. We then add that integer to the ASCII value of the character at the previous index to get the next character.